# How to get the CQ5 userInfo in java or jsp by using jackrabbit

Tags: aem, jackrabbit

How to get the CQ5 userInfo by using `org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user` like name and group information in java or jsp .?

Answer (score 10):

In JSP / Java you can adapt your resource to [UserManager](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.6/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/class-use/UserManager.html) class and get the current user or list down all the users and groups as per your requirement.

```
    Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
    UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
    /* to get the current user */
    Authorizable auth = userManager.getAuthorizable(session.getUserID());
    /* to get the property of the authorizable. Use relative path */
    Value[] names = auth.getProperty("./profile/familyName");
    /* to get the groups it is member of */
    Iterator<Group> groups = auth.memberOf();
```

To list all the users or groups, you can use findAuthorizables() method available in the UserManger.

You can also obtain the User info in JS using `CQ.User.getCurrentUser()` which would return an instance of the current [User](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.User), with which you can access the user's properties.