# How can we customize the page information menu options on a page in AEM6.1?

Tags: aem

When we open a page in touch UI, in the left side we have a Page Information dropdown. In that dropdown, there is a list of different options i.e Open Properties, Start Workflow, Publish Page, Lock Page etc. I need to remove some of them.Let's say I don't want Publish page option there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu items are defined in the following JSP which you need to overlay:`/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/pagestatus/pagestatus.jsp`

Comment: Thanks mickleroy! Just wanted to check if we can configure it for a specific template or a group?

Comment: Get a UserManager instance in the JSP and check the group the current user belongs to. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549502/how-to-get-the-cq5-userinfo-in-java-or-jsp-by-using-jackrabbit

Comment: @Ashwini if you could accept the answer that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!